# Unable to access any website after connecting to OPENVPN hosted on Digital Ocean, Am I missing any configuration step?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have followed this tutorial to setup VPN with Pi-Hole.
https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/overview/
till this page
https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/firewall/
as rest of tutorial is general info.

After completion, I am able to connect to to VPN using OpenVPN Connect also I can reach pi-hole admin page on installed on Ubuntu 18.04 on Digital Ocean Droplet through the VPN.

But after connecting to vpn I am not able to access internet or open any website.

Here is openvpn server config:

```
local 165.22.194.235
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 165.22.194.235"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

And my iptable rules:

```
root@crownedeagle:~# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:openvpn
9    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
10   REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:80 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
11   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https reject-with tcp-reset
12   REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
root@crownedeagle:~#
```

I want to use this vpn to access pi-hole to block ads.

What I am missing or doing wrong.
Which IP address should I use in the OpenVPN server config file, 10.8.0.1 or the IP Adress of the Digital Ocean Droplet??

Please help..

Comment: What does the routing on your machine look like? Did you setup a proxy so it actually uses the VPN? Are you able to access regular sites on your machine while the VPN is active?

Comment: @Seth No I am not able to access any regular site except the Pi-Hole admin page. I don't have any knowledge about routing, please explain if I am missing any step or config.

Comment: Are you cable to reach other sites from your server e.g. using the console? What did you do to tell your PC to use the VPN to access websites?

Comment: @Seth No I am not able to reach common websites from my server.. I tried curl ipinfo.io/geo which resulted in error message. "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipinfo.io" I tried this curl command through console using SSH

Comment: @Seth I am not using this VPN on PC..I am trying to use it on my mobile using OPENVPN Connect app.

Comment: @Seth Yesterday I went though exact steps to create droplet on Digital Ocean Bengluru, India area and install vpn and for 15 or 2p minutes my von woked fine but that time my Pi-Hole service was not able to block ads and after some time it working.. Also that time if I added push directive with 1.1.1.1 as DNS then I was able to access internet but no ad blocking.

Comment: Doesn't matter where you want to use it. But if you can't establish a connection to a site from your server that's is probably the reason why you can't use it. DNS resolution isn't working properly.

Comment: @Seth How can I fix it?

Comment: @Seth Is there any wrong entry? I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073249/openvpn-unable-to-browse-internet-after-connect-to-openvpn#5107000 and added iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE Does this may have caused the blocking of access to internet?